# css3 - different shades of background, without using images?

Tags: css

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzAJp

All divs have lightblue as background color, added by `background-color` css style, not by `background-image`.

I would like to make the second div a little darker, by combining its existing background color with  rgba(0,0,0,0.1). The point is to specify lightblue only once, for the `div` tag, and not to any classes.

Is it possible with css3, without using images as backgrounds?

Comment: That's a very interesting question. It seems that in the current CSS, using box-shadow is the simplest way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darker:

```
box-shadow: inset 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

Lighter:

```
box-shadow: inset 100px 100px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dzAJp/3/

---

### UPDATE

In the example code above we've set the dimensions to 100px to match that of the containing object. Obviously this isn't very portable if your elements aren't all 100px square.

To overcome this we can set an arbitrarily high pixel value (unfortunately `box-shadow` does not accept percentages):

```
box-shadow: inset 10000px 10000px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

And for one final note... Read the following link on `box-shadow` with regards to browser compatibility: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

Use the Box shadow property

like `box-shadow: inset 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);`

close to `0` for darker and close to `256` for lighter

Comment: You probably mean from 0 to 255.